# Call a method which has Graphics g as its parameters

Tags: java

Shape class has an abstract draw which takes a Graphics object... for example, if I want to draw a rectangle, in case 2 when I write:

```
shapetype.draw(g); // he said that g is undefined
```

how should I initialise g in order to call function draw(g):

```
    public class main extends Applet 
    {
        Shape shapetype; // shapeClass has 3 subclasses

        public void init() 
        {
            super.init();

// ask user to choose the type of shape 1-line 2-rectangle 3-oval
// int choice =  the type of shape         
            switch(choice)
            {

                case 1:
                // draw line
                    break;

                // draw Rectangle
                case 2:
                //ask user for x,y,width and height
                shapetype = new Rectangle(x1,y1,w,h);
                shapetype.draw(g); // to draw a rectangle
                    break;

                case 3:
              // draw Oval
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        {super.paint(g); }

    }
```

Comment: You need to have a instance member with graphics and have that inside switch.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the draw call to the `paint` method:

```
@Overrride // since you're overriding.
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    if(shapetype != null) {
        shapetype.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Drawing the shape only once will not be enough, it will get overwritten each time `paint` is called, so it needs to be redrawn.